# PHP7 compatibility

Tags: php, php-7

Im looking for fix for PHP7 compatibility.
I have code which working well with PHP 5.6.2.

Can you please help me to work with PHP7?

```
<?php 
$select = "SELECT post_title , ID FROM  wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 60";
$sql1= mysql_query($select);
$a = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){  ?>
div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" readonly value="<?php echo $row['post_title']; ?>" name="post_title-<?php echo $a; ?>" class="form-control abc1" id="post_title" placeholder="post_title">
<input type="hidden" readonly value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" name="ID-<?php echo $a; ?>" class="form-control abc1" id="post_title" placeholder="post_title">
</div>
<?php $a++;
}
?>
```

Thank you.
Best Regards
Jiri

Comment: mysql_* extension has been deprecated from php 7

Comment: Try using mysqli extensions; also, if you could post the errors you're getting, that'd be helpful. Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when running PHP 5.6.2 you should have seen the deprecation notices for the [`mysql_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php), and they have been completely removed in PHP 7. Fortunately, you can use the [`mysqli_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) without really changing your code much.

The primary difference in this example (aside from adding an `i` to your function names) is that now you'll need to explicitly use the link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect()` or `mysqli_init()` which is different because previously if the link identifier was not specified, then the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` was assumed. This is now required.

```
<?php

// get a link to the connection
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$select = "SELECT post_title , ID FROM  wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 60";

// use the link here
// change mysql_query -> mysqli_query
$sql1= mysqli_query($link, $select);

$a = 1;

// change mysql_fetch_array -> mysqli_fetch_array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){  ?>
div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" readonly value="<?php echo $row['post_title']; ?>" name="post_title-<?php echo $a; ?>" class="form-control abc1" id="post_title" placeholder="post_title">
<input type="hidden" readonly value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" name="ID-<?php echo $a; ?>" class="form-control abc1" id="post_title" placeholder="post_title">
</div>
<?php $a++;
}
?>
```

Comment: @JoeWatkins thanks for the hint. I've updated my answer.